# How to get motherboard serial in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, serial-number, motherboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get motherboard id or serial number ?[Delphi]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497253/how-to-get-motherboard-id-or-serial-number-delphi)

Is there any free component to get the motherboard serial number in Delphi?

Comment: May be duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497253/how-to-get-motherboard-id-or-serial-number-delphi

Comment: Doesn't work for Delphi 2010 , And as i said , i need a free component

Comment: @TOndrej: I know that the Stack Exchange software sometimes forget to mention that a question or answer has been changed, but it sure seems like he did say that ("is there any **free** component ?").

Comment: As far as I can see, RRUZ's approach would work perfectly in Delphi 2010, and WMI is a part of Windows (2000 and later), and since you are using Delphi, I guess one can assume that the end-users of your applications actually are using Windows (2000 and later), and have WMI "installed" already.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need a component : [MagWMI](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp) component allows access and update of windows system information using Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI)

Comment: We use MagWMI for low level hardware access (drive serial number, etc.) and are happy with it.  

Note to original poster: If you are thinking about using the motherboard serial number as part of a licensing scheme, as far as I know, motherboard serial numbers are not totally unique.  If you purchase 2 of the same boards, for example, they'll have the same serial number. (If others here know better, please correct me.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a free Delphi WMI library, have a look at [GLibWMI project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/) by StackOverflow user [Neftalí](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17487/neftali)