# How to use ManagementObjectSearcher in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, wmi, delphi-2007

I found on internet but I didn't got how can I use ManagementObjectSearcher in delphi. My main question which file I have to add in 'uses'.

I found [one code](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2009/10/09/accesing-wmi-info-with-delphi-prism/) but can't make it run in my system.

Comment: I assume you've tried the example with Delphi *Prism*?

Comment: @Lieven, I am using `delphi 2007`. Sorry, I forget to mention about that.

Comment: So, no such thing exist in delphi 2007?

Comment: I honestly have no idea but if you can't find it, it probably doesn't exists. That only means that the *mentioned snipped* won't work. It doesn't mean you can't write/adapt the code to make it work with Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 5):

Himadri, the code wich you refer uses the `ManagementObjectSearcher`  in `Delphi Prism`, the [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) is a .Net class for retrieve information about the [`WMI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx). you can access the WMI from delphi using 3 alternatives.

1) importing the `Microsoft WMIScripting Library` from Component->Import Component and then select Import type library.

```
program WMI_Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ActiveX,
  Variants,
  SysUtils,
  WbemScripting_TLB in '..\..\..\Documents\RAD Studio\5.0\Imports\WbemScripting_TLB.pas';//


Procedure AccessWMI;
var
  WMIServices : ISWbemServices;
  Root        : ISWbemObjectSet;
  Item        : Variant;
begin
  WMIServices := CoSWbemLocator.Create.ConnectServer('.', 'root\cimv2','', '', '', '', 0, nil);
  Root  := WMIServices.ExecQuery('Select Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem','WQL', 0, nil);
  Item := Root.ItemIndex(0);
  Writeln(VarToStr(Item.Caption));
end;


begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    AccessWMI;
    Readln;
    CoUninitialize;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    Begin
        CoUninitialize;
        Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
        Readln;
    End;
  end;
end.
```

2) use a COM late binding

```
program WMI_Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils
  ,ActiveX
  ,ComObj
  ,Variants;


Procedure AccessWMI;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;
    Moniker: IMoniker;
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2');
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 then
  Writeln(VarToStr(colItem.Caption));
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      AccessWMI;
      Readln;
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    Begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
        Readln;
    End;
  end;
end.
```

3) using  a WMI library, like the [GLibWMI VCL Component Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/)

[image]

you can found several samples in S.O about the [WMI and Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/WMI+Delphi)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497253/how-to-get-motherboard-id-or-serial-number-delphi/2497314#2497314 I have seen this answer already. I want the processor details. Using Win32_Processor

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use the `Delphi 2007 .Net` personality (if you have the RadStudio 2007) which is based on .NET Framework 2.0

check this sample to access the `ManagementObjectSearcher` from an `Delphi 2007 .Net` console application.

```
program WmiTest;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.Management,
  SysUtils;
var
Searcher   : ManagementObjectSearcher ;
Collection : ManagementObjectCollection;
iter       : ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator;
WmiObject  : ManagementObject;
begin
  try
    Searcher  :=ManagementObjectSearcher.Create('SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem');
    Collection:=Searcher.Get();
    iter:=Collection.GetEnumerator;
    while(iter.MoveNext()) do
    begin
      WmiObject:=ManagementObject(iter.Current);
      Writeln(WmiObject['Caption']);
    end;
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```