# Delphi: bugs while getting motherboard serial number

Tags: delphi, serial-number, motherboard

There are 2 good examples how to get a serial number: [How to get motherboard id or serial number in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497253/how-to-get-motherboard-id-or-serial-number-delphi)

All they work for me (Windows 7). But for 2 people they don't!

The Option 1 (Microsoft WMIScripting Library) returns an error which cannot be handled in an exception! (I tried to use my code in the exception but it was not performed). OS Windows 7:

[image]

The Option 2 (Windows XP) - returns nothing: no errors, no the serial number.

Can anybody explain why it is and is there a work code to do this?

There is a comment in that link: "@PRUZ And you know something about my second comment? that I check the same code in some other computer which returns 'none'. What's the matter with it? – Himadri"

Thanks!!!

Comment: -1, explain please, it is very interesting for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@maxfax, the first sample code does not work in Windows xp because uses the `ItemIndex` property which is available since windows vista for more details check this [article (`Be careful when you import the Microsoft WMIScripting Library`)](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/be-careful-when-you-import-the-microsoft-wmiscripting-library/).  the second snippet must work ok in any Windows system, because access the WMI properties using the name of the property directly. Now if the second option does not retrieve a serial number in any machine just is because the WMI provider does not expose information for this property. as side note some  Virtual Machines like VMWARE reports `None` as serial number .

**Update**

I just wrote an article on my blog about how read the SMBios ([`Reading the SMBios Tables using Delphi`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/reading-the-smbios-tables-using-delphi/)), using this method you get the serial number of the motherboard directly from the SMBios tables.

Comment: Ok, I will check the second option on many computers and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have tested on 3 laptops. One with Windows 7 shows "Base Serial Number" instead of a normal number. Therefor 2 out of 5 machines retrieve the serial incorrectly. I cannot rely on this method. Is there other way? Thanks!

Comment: @maxfax, the another method is read directly the `SMBIOS` tables and parse the information, check these WinApi functions `EnumSystemFirmwareTables` and `GetSystemFirmwareTable` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724379%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: If you don't mind, please gave an example how to use that function. Thanks!

Comment: I am in a shock. What do those 2 cods do? One said me that the second option shows the same serial on 2 machines today!!! 2 motheboards are Asus, but one is R5, other is R4!!!!

Comment: So the second option does not work completely or retrieves the same serials on 2 machines...Nobody says anything... Did not try?